# What is happening to my plants

Tags: diagnosis, succulents

I have a few plants together in the same pot. Most of them have the same symptoms: Part of them gets dark and shrink.

The dark part are not dry and the plant looks alive above it.

I think its like this for a few weeks/months.

[image]

[image]

PS: Wood chips is not my idea.

Comment: your soil looks a bit wet. How often do you water? Does your pot have a drain hole?

Comment: did you move the woodchips  away from the other plant in the second image to show the base of the stems for diagnostic purposes on here?

Comment: no, its an other pot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is to do with watering. Succulent have modified leaves capable of holding water during drought.

Too much watering will close the stomata ans reduce/stop photosynthesis and eventually kill the plant which is unable to produce food for itself.

Water less. Take the wood chips out and replace with horticultural grit to avoid leaves being splashed.

Comment: I water every ~ 3 weeks

Comment: Is it because the soil does not drain well and there is no evacuation ? Also there are inside with no direct sun light.

Comment: The soil was wet. I'll let it dry outside in a shady location. Thanks !